# Pascal: Incompatible types: got "LONGINT" expected "CHAR"

Tags: error-handling, char, pascal

I keep getting the "98 / 39 comp1_~1.pas
 Error: Incompatible types: got "LONGINT" expected "CHAR". This is concerning line 6. Any help please.

```
Function RollBowlDie(VirtualDiceGame : Boolean) : Integer;
  Var
    BowlDieResult : Char;
  Begin
      If VirtualDiceGame
      Then BowlDieResult := Random(6) + 1
      Else
        Begin
        Repeat
          Writeln('Please roll the bowling die and then enter your result.');
          Writeln;
          Writeln('Enter 1 if the result is a 1');
          Writeln('Enter 2 if the result is a 2');
          Writeln('Enter 3 if the result is a 4');
          Writeln('Enter 4 if the result is a 6');
          Writeln('Enter 5 if the result is a 0');
          Writeln('Enter 6 if the result is OUT');
          Writeln;
          Write('Result: ');
          Readln(BowlDieResult);
          If not (BowlDieResult in ['1'..'6'])
          Then
              Begin
              Writeln;
              Writeln('That was not one of the allowed options. Please try agai:');
              End;
          Until BowlDieResult in ['1'..'6'];
        End;
RollBowlDie := Ord(BowlDieResult)  - Ord('0');
  End;
```

Comment: The compiler told you exactly what the problem is. Random returns a number, and BowlDieResult is a char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what's the problem?

`BowlDieResult` is a `char` but you're assigning a `longint` to it.

My pascal is a bit rusty, but try

```
 BowlDieResult := chr(49 + Random(6));
```

Comment: I see! Didn't know you could do that thanks. How does this work? Does it interpret it as char I take it?

Comment: I'm assuming that `chr()` will accept a `longint` as parameter (reasonable, I think) and converts it to a `char`. I'm also assuming that `Random(6)` produces an integer in the range 0..5 and the `chr()` converts it to '0'..'6'.

Comment: You're welcome. I should have said "the `chr()` converts it to '1'..'6' " but you probably realised that.