# Equivalent of C++ ( cin >> n) in delphi

Tags: delphi

I need to read an unknown amount of integer numbers from standard input. I know that in C++ it can be easily realized by:

```
while ( cin >> n )
```

Is there any way to realise the same in Delphi?

Comment: ReadLn() with a while or repeat loop will work. You can find an example (using Char, but the concept is the same) [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6076797/62576)

Comment: It's a bit more complex in Delphi. `ReadLn`, as suggested by @Ken, reads an entire line and returns a string, which could potentially contain multiple integer values. I'm not aware of anything directly comparable to `cin >> n`. I think you need to parse input yourself.

Comment: @KenWhite, I suppose simple read will work, but I cannot find anywhere what conditions does the while/repeat loop need?

Comment: Whatever condition you want to end the loop. I can't tell you what that would be, because I don't know what you're doing. How would you end the loop in your C++ code?

Comment: @David: No, `ReadLn` does not return a string. `var X: Integer = 0; begin ReadLn(X); // Enter 9  WriteLn(X * 10); // Outputs 90 ReadLn; end.`

Comment: @KenWhite, u mean the body of the loop? It can consist of whatever u want, for example, if it's needed to calculate the number of elelments in the input, it would be smth like `++counter`, where `counter` is a variable.

Comment: @KenWhite, it would work only if there is a single number in input. If input is like _1 2 3 4 5_, then it would read as a string

Comment: @KenWhite OK, but in order to match the behaviour of `cin >> n` you have to read as text and parse it because `cin >> n` caters for multiple values in a single line. Perhaps `Read(n)` suffices. You ask about the condition to end the loop in the C++ code, but there's nothing more to be said than is in the question. The condition is stated very clearly. The loop if `while ( cin >> n ) { ... }` and it terminates when `cin >> n` evaluates false.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, understood. That's why I do not like school tasks, connected with Delphi xD.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: As you said, you can't exactly match the behavior of `cin`. Thanks for the DV.

Comment: @KenWhite You can, but you have to code it yourself

Answer (score 4):

This should be quite near:

```
  while not EoF do
    Read(n);
```

You can also write your own CIn function to catch any wrong input like this:

```
function CIn(out I: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if not EoF then begin
    try
      Read(I);
    except
      Exit;
    end;
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

Note that `Read` will only return when a line ending or end of file is available. So when you have multiple integers in one line, the first one is returned when the line end is given.

I should also mention that the behavior of the C++ function is way more complex than what can be accomplished with Delphi built-in methods. It would help if you can list the specific requirements for your task to give a solid solution.

Comment: This isn't the same.  The C++ loop terminates either when there is no more input, or the intput doesn't contain an integer.

Comment: Mmm, @Uwe, I thought eof works only with the files, doesn't it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, note the "quite near". I tested with a console application. Entering invalid data raises an exception, but that is actually expected. The loop terminates when pressing <Ctrl>-Z/<Enter> or obviously <Ctrl>-C.

Comment: @Niklex, _Input_ is similar to a file from the programs perspective. In addition we can as well write just `while not EoF do` because the compiler assumes _Input_ when no parameter is given.

Comment: In the c++ variant, invalid data would result in the loop terminating and no characters  being extracted. Does Read extract in that scenario?